# sumar del 1 al 100 los numeros primos

Tags: bash, script

```
#!/bin/bash

j=100
i=3
tem=2
flag=0
```

esto comprueba si es primo el numero

```
while [ $i -ne $j ]; do 

temp=`echo $i`

while [ $temp -ne $tem ]; do

temp=`expr $temp - 1`
n=`expr $i % $temp`
```

esto define si es primo o no

```
if [ $n -eq 0 -a $flag -eq 0 ]; then

flag=1

fi

done
```

esto deberia sumar los numeros primos

```
if [ $flag -eq 0 ]; then 

i2=$i
((i++))
i3=$(calc $i+$i2)
echo "$i3"
else

flag=0
((i++))
fi

done
```

ya ni se como continuar, me imagino donde esta el fallo pero ni idea de como hacer lo que pido, muchas gracias.

Comment: pon cada cosa en una función y llámalas

Answer (score 0):

te dejo un código explicado de cómo lo podrías hacer ya que el tuyo daba muchos errores, por ejemplo en la línea de `i3=$(calc $i+$i2)`, no sé de dónde sale ese `calc`.

```
#!/bin/bash
n=0
sum=0
sumar_si_primo()
{
    #empezamos a evaluar a partir del 2
    i=2 
    #bandera para evaluar si es primo o no. Si está a 1 quiere decir que no es primo
    flag=0 
    #iremos probando hasta que i sea la mitad del número a comprobar
    #(no es necesario probar hasta el mismo número)
    while test $i -le `expr $n / 2` 
    do
        ##Si al dividir i por el número nos da resto 0, entonces no es primo
        if test `expr $n % $i` -eq 0 
        then
            flag=1
        fi
        i=`expr $i + 1`#Avanzamos i al siguiente número
    done 
    if test $flag -ne 1
    then
        sum=$((sum + $n)) #Sumamos este número ya que es primo
    fi
    echo "$n%" #Para observar el progreso de la ejecución
}


#for para recorrer y sumar los primos del 1 al 100
for n in {1..100}
do
    sumar_si_primo
done

echo "$sum"
```

La salida obtenida deberia ser `1061`.
Espero que con la explicación del código lo puedas entender mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Me inspiré en la respuesta de Daniel, pero cree mi propia versión separando todo en funciones y volviéndolo más expresivo (según yo):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

es_primo() {
    local -i numero=$1

    local -i ES_PRIMO=0
    local -i NO_ES_PRIMO=1
    local -i flag=0
    local -i mitad=$((numero/2))

    (( numero == 1 )) && return $NO_ES_PRIMO

    for ((i=2; i <= mitad; i++)); do
        (( numero % i == 0 )) && ((flag++))
    done

    (( flag == 0 )) && return $ES_PRIMO
    return $NO_ES_PRIMO
}

sumar_primos() {
    local -i inicio=$1
    local -i fin=$2

    local -i suma

    [[ $fin -eq 0 ]] && { fin=$inicio; inicio=2 ; }

    for ((numero=inicio; numero <= fin; numero++)); do
     es_primo $numero && ((suma+=numero))
    done

    echo $suma
}

suma=$(sumar_primos 13 17)

echo "Suma: $suma"
```

Me parece que el script se explica por si mismo: primero iteramos entre el rango de enteros, luego checamos con una funcion si es primo, y si es, lo suma a un acumulador.

El resultado del script sería:

```
$ ./primo.sh
Suma: 30
```

Dentro del script podría adaptar el rango de numeros a buscar. Si sólo pones un número al lado de la función `sumar_primos`, se asume que el inicio de búsqueda será 1, y el primer parámetro el máximo.